# image cache iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, caching, uiimage

this is a part of my code. I'm using a asyncImageView .Everything work good. But now i want to save in the iphone all images in a path. I know i have to use NSFileManager but where?
EDIT: now i try with my code but nothing save when i compile on my iphone

```
// Configure the cell.

NSDictionary *dico = [self.pseudoOnline objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.pseudo.text = [dico objectForKey:@"pseudo"];
cell.sexe.text    = [dico objectForKey:@"sexe"];
cell.age.text     = [dico objectForKey:@"age"];


UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dico objectForKey:@"photo"]]]];  


NSString *deskTopDir = @"/Users/***/Desktop/imagesOnline";



NSString *nomPhoto = [[cell.pseudo text]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];;

NSLog(@"pseudo%@",nomPhoto);



NSString *jpegFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpeg",deskTopDir,nomPhoto];

NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5f)]; quality
[data2 writeToFile:jpegFilePath atomically:YES];

NSLog(@"image %@",jpegFilePath);

[image release];



CGRect frame;

frame.size.width=45; frame.size.height=43;

frame.origin.x=-5; frame.origin.y=0;

asyncImageView *asyncImage = [[[asyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];

asyncImage.tag =999;


[asyncImage loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dico objectForKey:@"photo"]]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImage];



return cell;
```

so now it works i can download all the pictures. But now i want to load them

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `asyncImageView` is, but it appears to get an image.
If it gets the image the way your code implies, you can put your `NSFileManger` method call right after:

```
 [cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImage];
```

If, on the other hand, the `asyncImageView` fetches the image asynchronously (as it's name implies), then you should put your `NSFileManager` method call in `asyncImageView's` callback delegate.

Basically, as soon as you actually have the image, you can save the image.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting an image?  Are you sure "dico" is giving you a valid string?  NSLog the values to be sure.

Comment: Also NSLog the image itself:  NSLog(@"Image is 0x%x",image);   And, check the return value of the createFileAtPath: call - it returns a success/failure boolean.

Comment: What have you tried?  Gentle reminder: SO is not about people writing code for you, it's about getting un-stuck in your own code.  If you have problems loading an image from a file, search SO for that topic.  If nothing turns up (unlikely), then ask another question.